# Grease Pencil 'shimmers' with every frame in viewport

Tags: objects, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine, grease-pencil, units

I have a video below, If you see carefully the lines are shimmering, Is there any way to avoid that?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBIJbTTiLlU
I tried increasing samples of viewport
I tried increasing anti-aliasing of grease pencil.
Tried different render systems 'eevee' and 'cycles'.
Tried all possible outputs but the problem is in the viewport itself.Should I try denoising it? although that didn't work so well either
The problem just isn't going way. Please help!

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.blender.org/T76886 ?

Comment: it definitely looks like an antialiasing issue, I used to have those with older blender versions. Are all the drawings GP objects or are they image textures? Did you try increasing the grease-pencil anti-aliasing setting past the soft limit of 2, like 10 or 100?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. They all are GP objects. I tried increasing anti-aliasing to 200 even. It didn't work